# How to gift an entire BTC wallet via QR code?

Tags: wallet, qrcode, gifting-bitcoin

I have a unique scenario where I'd like to:

- Create a BTC wallet and add a small amount of funds to it.
- Generate a QR code that contains the private key.
- Then gift that QR code to a friend so they can import the BTC.

I'm basically trying to replicate something like a Casascius coin but I'm unsure of the exact steps to take in making all this work.

Could I simply put my 24 seed words into the QR and somehow the recipient could take ownership that way?

To clarify: I understand you should never give out your private key under normal circumstances. This is an exercise in figuring out how to gift an entire wallet that I would no longer personally use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can encode the mnemonic phrase i.e. the "entire wallet" in a QR code. Most wallet software will not allow exporting a mnemonic as a QR code though since that often leads to bad security practises (e.g. taking screenshots).

I would suggest using [BlueWallet](https://bluewallet.io/) since it's very easy to use and already encodes the mnemonic in a QR code for you when displaying the backup through <kbd>•••</kbd> > <kbd>Export/Backup</kbd>.

The recipient of your gift simply needs to download BlueWallet and scan the QR code to import and effectively own the wallet.

**However**, you're not really "gifting" bitcoin here since you still have access to the wallet. There is no on-chain change of ownership. The recipient might want to send the funds on the gift wallet to one only they themselves have access to.

---

Personally, I think it would be best (and also the better learning experience for the recipient) if you just create a gift transaction to a freshly created wallet on their phone and explain what's happening along the way.

Comment: Exactly the info I was looking for, thank you!